# Drupal simplenews succuess message doesn't display

Tags: php, drupal

In my drupal site when a user enter a email address to the newsletter on the right side block. The success message doesn't display therefore, I checked the  `simplenews_subscriptions_page_form_submit()` function and it's actually setting the message like

```
 if (simplenews_confirmation_send_combined()) {
        drupal_set_message(t('You will receive a confirmation e-mail shortly containing further instructions on how to complete your subscription.'));

      }
```

And after I've debug the drupal_get_messages() function to see is any value any values returns for it and Yes it is as

`Array ( [status] => Array ( [0] => You will receive a confirmation e-mail shortly containing further instructions on how to complete your subscription. )`

But in the font-theme doesn't display anything I also checked theme_status_messages() function it actually initially checked for  `$display = $variables['display'];` then when I debug this value it's printing always empty but `$variables['display']` value is set.

Could any please let me know how to fix this ?

FYI: I'm using Drupal v7

Comment: You might have better luck at the Drupal SE site: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that $messages variable is mentioned in the theme getting called ?
If not, mention  in the page.tpl.php

Comment: thanks man reminding about this. when I checked the page.tpl.php for $message variable. It's not called for home page and I've now update it to work home page.